# anyone use swagger for web api documentation see this error at runtime?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

Please enable "XML documentation file" in project properties with default (bin\EnterpriseServices.XML) value or edit value in App_Start\SwaggerNet.cs

Comment: found the answer here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x4sa0ak0(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, from the [git documentation](https://github.com/Swagger-Net/Swagger.Net#configuration)

> Enable "XML documentation file" and accept the default value, or
>   specify a custom value (i.e. App_Data\Docs.XML), in the Web API's
>   properties | Build menu (Alt+Enter). If you specify a custom value,
>   you will need to edit the App_Start\SwaggerNet.cs file.

This means, go to your project's Properties > Build > Output
Then check the box for "XML documentation file"
You can either accept the default or specify your own. If you specify a custom value, you will need to edit the App_Start\SwaggerNet.cs file

Comment: the link i posted earlier (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x4sa0ak0(v=vs.100).aspx) has the same info.  Thanks for clarifying.